Does the official SeaMonkey "Water Purifier" contain eggs?
Question: Does the official SeaMonkey "Water Purifier" contain eggs? Or is exclusively minerals and water conditioner?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

The water conditioner is just a water conditioner. Eggs are packaged separately.

@keshlam the main concern surrounding if the Water Purifier packet contains SeaMonkey eggs is because it has been alleged that in Scott, Sharon's book "Toys and American Culture: An Encyclopedia" he states they (at least at some point) included the eggs. https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea-Monkeys#Use
I am curious if they still attempt this practice.

I doubt you are going to get an answer to that here, since the answer may have changed fifteen times since that book was published. Make a purchase, run the experiment, and tell us. Assuming you are that interested in brine shrimp.

there is hundreds of different SeaMonkey and brine shrimp kits for sale,some has the eggs and minerals mixed others have them separate.most kits has 3 bags or containers,minerals-eggs-food.

@trondhansen As stated in the post, my question regards the Sea Monkeys as distributed by their official organization: https://www.sea-monkeys.com/about-the-sea-monkeys/

Sea-Monkeys is a marketing term for a specific artificial breed of brine shrimp (Artemia) developed by Harold von Braunhut.

the answer is on this page https://www.sea-monkeys.com/sea-monkey-set-up-instructions/ looks like you have to read the instructions :)

@trondhansen Can I convince you to write that up as a quick answer?
